# Running jquery function after one function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am adding some comments with AJAX and get return formatted HTML and adding it to HTML with DOM manipulation,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "index.php/user/news/add_comment",
    data: $("#comment_fm").serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {

        var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if (objData.cival == 1) //Success..
        {
            $("#comment").val('');
            $("#comment_box").replaceWith(objData.comment);
            $("#commentcounts").replaceWith(objData.commentcounts);
        }

    } // Success End
}); //AJAX End
```

With above code i can see my comments are added,
Now in same return formatted HTML, there is delete button which have JS function associated,

Below is delete JS,

```
function deletecomment(commentid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "index.php/user/news/deletecomment",
        data: {
            comment_id: commentid
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if (objData.cival == 1) {
                $("#commentcounts").replaceWith(objData.commentcounts);
                $("#commentbox" + commentid).remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my delete button which fire to function deletecomment()

```
<a href="javascript:deletecomment(<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-trash text-info"></i></a>
```

But my problem is that i can not delete this comment just after adding function is run,
If i refresh page, then delete function works a needed,

So question is, how to make multiple function work without reloading page?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You haven't shown the events that result in these functions being called, but I suspect you want to look at jQuery .on() to attach the event handler instead of using .click() : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: so what currently happens when you try to delete? what error are you getting in dev tools? can you reproduce in a fiddle? is the data coming back from the php script updated after adding?

Comment: `.live` is oldschool (deprecated), you should use `.on` moving forward

Comment: @Matt.C I do not recommend .live() since it is deprecated as of JQuery 1.7

Comment: @Matt.C `live() is dead`, use `on()` passing `selector` param instead

Comment: changed my comment, sorry, was living in the past

Comment: I added my event JS in code above

Comment: Why don't you just add a `class` to your `delete button` in your returned `html` once the comment gets added and just bind an event on button like `$(document).on('click','.youraddedClass',function(){//delete functionality});`

Comment: please show how you are firing the functions (events/ui etc)

Comment: @atmd, added my event code which trigger to delete function

Comment: you are loading the value from `$comment['comment_id'];` on page load, which is a php variable.

when you come to delete a comments that added it wont work as the `$comment['comment_id'];` isn't updated and doesn't relate to an existing comment. Which is why it works on refresh but not after adding a new comment

Comment: you are firing the function inline, so there shouldn't be any issues with binding or `.on` etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try as below:

```
<a class="deleteComment" data-id="<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash text-info"></i></a>
```

Your JS would be:

```
$(document).on('click','.deleteComment',function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
          url: baseURL + "index.php/user/news/deletecomment",
          data: {
                 comment_id: $(this).data('id');
          },
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
                var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (objData.cival == 1) {
                     $("#commentcounts").replaceWith(objData.commentcounts);
                     $("#commentbox" + commentid).remove();
                }
          }
    });
});
```